# Run Two Services in One container Docker

Tags: python, docker, celery, gunicorn

Below is my Docker File, I am creating an image of it and starting my container:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

My `docker-entrypoint.sh` is as follow :

```
set -eo pipefail

if [ "${#}" -ne 0 ]; then
    exec "${@}"
else
    gunicorn \
        --bind  "0.0.0.0:${SUPERSET_PORT}" \
        --access-logfile '-' \
        --error-logfile '-' \
        --workers 10 \
        --worker-class gthread \
        -k gevent \
        --threads 20 \
        --timeout 6000 \
        --limit-request-line 0 \
        --limit-request-field_size 0 \
        "${FLASK_APP}"
    celery --app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app worker -Ofair -l INFO    
fi
```

gunicorn server is running fine but the celery worker are not coming up, is there anything i am doing wrong here ?

Update After Answer :

```
 gunicorn \
        --bind  "0.0.0.0:${SUPERSET_PORT}" \
        --access-logfile '-' \
        --error-logfile '-' \
        --workers 10 \
        --worker-class gthread \
        -k gevent \
        --threads 20 \
        --timeout 6000 \
        --limit-request-line 0 \
        --daemon \
        --limit-request-field_size 0 \
        "${FLASK_APP}" &\
    celery --app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app worker -Ofair -l INFO
```

Comment: End the `gunicorn` command with an `&` to run it in the background. As it is now, the celery command won't run until the gunicorn command finishes.

Comment: Why do these have to be the same container?  If you remove this entrypoint script, you could `docker run your-image celery --app=...`, running a second container with the same image but a different command.

Comment: @HansKilian I have updated the question after your comment I am doing it correctly not able to run celery

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that once flow reach the gunicorn part, this will block and will not release till gunicorn exits / returns something.

I would consider using [supervisor (process control system)](http://supervisord.org/)

On the other hand, if you would like quick fix to test things, I'd suggest to use `--daemon` (or `-D`) flag, which will not block the execution flow and detach the process ([see docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html))

Comment: I have updated my question after your answer is I am doing correctly not able to run celery